# Flex viewstack keeps redrawing invisible child, how to fix?

Tags: apache-flex, memory, viewstack

The situation: I've got a `ViewStack` with 2 children (both of type `Panel`).
The application starts with child 1 as the `SelectedChild`.

With a click on a button, child 2 is the SelectedChild. After that, I return to child 1 being the SelectedChild.

When I click `Show Redraw Regions` in the Flash Player, I can see child 2 being redrawn the whole time (i've got some moving objects in child 2). How can I prevent this from happening? Or can this only be done with actually removing the invisible (in this case child 2) child?

Why I want to achieve this? Child 2 will contain pretty much data (flv's, images, etc.) and when it's being *cached* like what happens now, it will slow down my application.

Comment: did u try calling `video.stop()`, `animation.stop()` etc before switching to a different tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out: the only way seems to actually remove the child, or it's moving/animated content.

Calling `video.stop()`, `animation.stop()` like Amarghosh mentioned should help too.

Answer (score 1):

A major source of inefficiency in Flash can come from invisible objects on your display list.  Not only do they continue to cause redraw region refreshes ("red rectangles"), they impose CPU penalties on Flash processing whenever the player needs to traverse the display list tree.  Mouseovers are notably more expensive, even if you don't have any MouseEvent listeners, when the display list is larger.  Any display list containing more than a couple thousand objects can start to feel the pain.

Long story short, sometimes performance dictates that you write your own "visibility manager" to swap objects in and out of the parent hierarchy as an alternative to toggling DisplayObject.visible.